# Share file with other Apps in android

Tags: android, file, share

I want to pass a file (i.e. .pdf, .png) from my android app to other apps on the device. I have read therefore the links [setting Up file sharing](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) and [sharing a file](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html). The files I want to share are not stored in my App, but I get them dynamically through `URL` links. What is the optimal way to share the files in that case? Is it necessary to store them in the App-store? And which path should I specify then as sharing path in `Manifest.xml file`?

**Update:**

I do not want to store the files in an external-Storage but in my App-Storage. I save a file as:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir() , "fileName");
```

My question is what path I should specify in the FileProvider Configuartion as the sharing path in that case? Or is it not necessary in this case?

Comment: Store the files in external or removable media. You don't have to add that path to the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the optimal way to share the files in that case?

Download the files, then share them.

> And which path should I specify then as sharing path in Manifest.xml file?

If you mean for a `FileProvider` configuration, you configure `FileProvider` to serve the files from wherever you are downloading them.

Comment: @arjacsoh: "My question is what path I should specify in the FileProvider Configuartion as the sharing path in that case?" -- Use `<files-path/>`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider for a sample project that serves files out of `getFilesDir()` using a `FileProvider`.

Comment: how can i download the filr as temporary file and share to a sharable media and automatically delete that file after sharing